# Angular - split build process to separately compile core app and custom-related code and join it together

Tags: angular, angular-cli

### Problem description

I have Angular app which is distributed in several custom versions (for different clients). This includes different styles and different configuration values for every version.

At the moment my build process looks like this:

For each custom version I perform two steps:

- all the custom code is copied into my `src` directory and then
- `ng build -c prod`

It is inefficient because I build my app several times just to only include minor client-related changes.

**I would like to build my app only once**, and reuse it to create all other final distributions, by including in my compiled app dist tar some precompiled and cached custom module or subapp for each client.

Im looking for a way to add this **custom part** of code after build and still be able to use defined in it configs and use their value in DI providers in AppModule.

### What I found so far

1. I could use config JSON's fetched from assets directory as described in this article:
   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/

This way will work if I change my typescript files to JSON files and include them in assets. I could switch this files after build. but I'm still wondering if it is possible to achive my goal using angular modules or subapps.

2. I found article describing spliting app to subapps, but if I understand it correctly, even with code splited to `app` and `subapp` I would have to build the whole project to be able to use config values from `subapp` and provide it in `app`'s AppModule.
   https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527